# Tensorflow to PyTorch - model.predict equivalent

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

1. I am attempting to retrieve the mean squared error of my training. within the original code based in TensorFlow, I am moving this code over to PyTorch (for research reasons).

   the original TensorFlow code:

```
    print("Calculating threshold")
    x_opt_predictions = model.predict(x_opt)
    print("Calculating MSE on optimization set...")
    mse = np.mean(np.power(x_opt - x_opt_predictions, 2), axis=1)
    print("mean is %.5f" % mse.mean())
    print("min is %.5f" % mse.min())
    print("max is %.5f" % mse.max())
    print("std is %.5f" % mse.std())
    tr = mse.mean() + mse.std()
```

the training method of pytorch:

```
def train(net, x_train, x_opt, BATCH_SIZE, EPOCHS, input_dim):
    outputs = 0
    mse = 0
    optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
    loss = 0
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        for i in tqdm(range(0, len(x_train), BATCH_SIZE)):
            batch_y = x_opt[i:i + BATCH_SIZE]
            
            net.zero_grad()
            
            outputs = net(batch_y)
            

            loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        print(f"Epoch: {epoch}. Loss: {loss}")
        print("opt", x_opt.size(), "output", outputs.__sizeof__())

    # VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
    return np.mean(np.power(x_opt - outputs, 2), axis=1)
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

2. as seen above the line "outputs" is not a numpy array of predictions, and acquiring this equivalent to generate the threshold
3. If there are any other (improved or missing) ways to acquire this value, appreciation in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The variable output is a pytorch tensor to convert it to numpy all you have to change is change this line of code `return np.mean(np.power(x_opt - outputs, 2), axis=1)` to this `return np.mean(np.power(x_opt - outputs.cpu().data.numpy(), 2), axis=1)` That will convert the tensor to a numpy array. If you are not using cuda with your network you do not need the .cpu() part.

Comment: well i still might have some underlying issue with my data then, now i get:
```ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (92334,10) (46,10) ```

Comment: That is because when you are subtracting outputs from x_opt you are just using the outputs from the last step not from the entire epoch so the x_opt has a much larger batch_size because it is the entire dataset while the outputs is just part of the dataset. You could instead use mse variable and add to it every step and return that it at the end of the epoch. Like this `mse += np.mean(np.power(batch_y - outputs.cpu().data.numpy(), 2), axis=1)` Then at the end just `return mse ` Instead of using x_opt you would use batch_y because they are referring to the same input and have the same size.